# Cognito custom email sender - decryption html entities

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to setup a custom email sender trigger for AWS Cognito. Users are created by a subsystem using cognito's admin-create-user command. This triggers an email with an initial one-time-password. Everything works 90% of the time.

Sometime the decrypted password contains a symbol that is represented as an html entity, while cognito expects the user to enter the real symbol

**Decrypted value inside the lambda email sender (that gets sent to the user):**

`iPi1Hz&gt;H` (note the `&gt;` part)

**Correct password:**

`iPi1Hz>H`

Decryption part of my lambda custom email sender

```
const getPlainTextCode = async (event: CustomEmailSenderTriggerEvent) => {
  if (!event.request.code) {
    throw Error("Could not find code");
  }

  if (!process.env.KEY_ID) {
    throw Error("Cannot decrypt code");
  }

  const client = buildClient(CommitmentPolicy.REQUIRE_ENCRYPT_ALLOW_DECRYPT);
  const generatorKeyId = process.env.KEY_ALIAS;
  const keyIds = [process.env.KEY_ID];
  const keyring = new KmsKeyringNode({ generatorKeyId, keyIds });

  let plainTextCode: string | undefined = undefined;
  const decryptOutput = await client.decrypt(keyring, Buffer.from(event.request.code, "base64"));
  if (event.userPoolId !== decryptOutput.messageHeader.encryptionContext["userpool-id"]) {
    throw new Error("Encryption context does not match expected values!");
  }
  plainTextCode = decryptOutput.plaintext.toString(); // this outputs iPi1Hz&gt;H

  return plainTextCode;
};
```

Comment: Were you ever able to get an answer for this?

Comment: No unfortunately not, you can circumvent the issue (if it still persists) by setting your own temporary password during cognito user creation, using a custom alphabet / set of symbols

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I think the issue lies on the email side though (when the user opens the email). I am using SendGrid and Twilio SMS for my verification emails, and when I use the `&` symbol in the password and send to both, text message is fine, but email shows `&amp;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue, one on the team solved it using a function that unresolves reserved characters, like this

```
function unescapeReservedCharacters(plainTextCode) {
   return plainTextCode
     .replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
     .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
     .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
     .replace(/&#39;/g, "'")
     .replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
}
```

and used on the plainTextCode object like so

```
let plainTextCode = undefined;
try {
  plainTextCode = await getPlainTextCode(event);
  plainTextCode = unescapeReservedCharacters(plainTextCode)
} catch (error) {
  throw Error(`Could not decrypt code: ${error}`);
}
```

credits:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html#enable-custom-email-sender-lambda-trigger
- https://repost.aws/questions/QULyhokZdMRwy06gVs6yq_pg/cognito-custom-email-sender-code-property-url-encoded